# Jquery to expand/collapse gridview row not working for the second row of the gridview

Tags: jquery, gridview, expand

It is working absolutely fine on clicking the first image control in the first row of the gridview but for the second row, when I am clicking the same Plus image with id as imgPlus, it's not working. The JQuery is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imgPlus").on("click", function () {

                if ($(this).attr("src") == "Images/Plus.JPG") {
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
                    $(this).attr("src", "Images/Minus.JPG")

                }
                else {
                       $(this).attr("src", "Images/Plus.JPG");
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's an `id` - `imgPlus`. Make it a class.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @PEJK 31?

Comment: `id` has to be unique. So if there are multiple `id`s of the same value, then the change will occur only on the first element with the mentioned `id`. If you wish to apply same logic on multiple elements, use `class`

Comment: Okay...Now I got it. Thanks very much for your help. @PEJK 31